# On the weak convergence of sub-probability measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Denote by $M(\mathbb R)$ the collection of sub-probability measures. Let $(\mu_n)_{n\ge 1}\subset M(\mathbb R)$ and $\mu\in M(\mathbb R)$. Do we have the equivalence of the following claims :

1. $\mu_n$ converges to $\mu$ under the weak convergence, i.e.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int fd\mu_n = \int f d\mu\quad \mbox{ holds for all continuous and bounded functions } f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R;$$

2. $\lim_{n\to\infty}d(F_{\mu_n},F_{\mu})=0$, where $F_{\mu_n}$ (resp. $F_{\mu}$) denotes the cumulative distribution function of $\mu_n$ (resp. $\mu$) and $d$ stands for the Lévy–Prokhorov metric, i.e.

$$d(F_{\mu_n},F_{\mu}) ~:=~ \inf\Big\{\epsilon>0 :\quad  F_{\mu}(x-\epsilon)-\epsilon\le F_{\mu_n}(x) \le F_{\mu}(x+\epsilon)+\epsilon\quad \mbox{ for all } x\in\mathbb R\Big\};$$

3. $\lim_{n\to\infty}F_{\mu_n}(x)=F_{\mu}(x)$ holds for all the continuity points of $F_{\mu}$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\big(\lim_{x\to\infty}F_{\mu_n}(x)\big)=\lim_{x\to\infty}F_{\mu}(x)$.

Thanks Nate Eldredge and Iosif Pinelis for pointing out the condition missing in 3. Now I consider the one-point compactification, i.e. $\overline{\mathbb R}:=\mathbb R\cup \{\infty\}$. Accordingly, denote by $M(\overline{\mathbb R})$ the set of probability measures on $\overline{\mathbb R}$. Let $(\overline\mu_n)_{n\ge 1}\subset M(\overline{\mathbb R})$ and $\overline\mu\in M(\overline{\mathbb R})$. Do we have still have the similar equivalence  :

1. $\overline\mu_n$ converges to $\overline\mu$ under the weak convergence, i.e.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int fd\overline\mu_n = \int f d\overline\mu\quad \mbox{ holds for all continuous and bounded functions } f:\overline{\mathbb R}\to\mathbb R;$$

2. $\lim_{n\to\infty}d(F_{\overline\mu_n},F_{\overline\mu})=0$, where $F_{\overline\mu_n}$ (resp. $F_{\overline\mu}$) denotes the cumulative distribution function of $\overline\mu_n$ (resp. $\overline\mu$) and $d$ stands for the Lévy–Prokhorov metric, i.e.

$$d(F_{\overline\mu_n},F_{\overline\mu}) ~:=~ \inf\Big\{\epsilon>0 :\quad  F_{\overline\mu}(x-\epsilon)-\epsilon\le F_{\overline\mu_n}(x) \le F_{\overline\mu}(x+\epsilon)+\epsilon\quad \mbox{ for all } x\in\overline{\mathbb R}\Big\};$$

3. $\lim_{n\to\infty}F_{\overline\mu_n}(x)=F_{\overline\mu}(x)$ holds for all the continuity points of $F_{\overline\mu}$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\big(\lim_{x\to\infty}F_{\overline\mu_n}(x)\big)=\lim_{x\to\infty}F_{\overline\mu}(x)$.

Here we note that there may exist a discontinuity at $\infty$, i.e. $\lim_{x\to\infty}F_{\overline\mu}(x)\neq F_{\overline\mu}(\infty)$.

Comment: Take for instance $\mu_n = \delta_n$ a point mass at $n$, and $\mu = 0$ the zero measure.  Then (3) holds but (1) does not (take $f=1$) nor does (2).

Comment: I think it should not be hard to show (1) and (2) equivalent though.  Either one implies $\mu_n(\mathbb{R}) \to \mu(\mathbb{R})$ and then you can renormalize the measures to reduce to the case for probability measures (with $\mu = 0$ being a special case).

Comment: If you add to condition 3 the requirement that $F_{\mu_n}(\infty)\to F_{\mu}(\infty)$, then I think you can easily modify the standard arguments to get the equivalence of the three conditions.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Thanks. Here when you talk about $F_{\mu}(\infty)$, you refer to $F_{\mu}(\infty):=\lim_{x\to\infty}F_{\mu}(x)$. Is it correct?

Comment: @NateEldredge Many thanks. Indeed, my concern is to consider the capacitation of the space of functions $f:\mathbb R\to [0,1]$ that are non-decreasing and cadlag by adding $\infty$.

Comment: @NateEldredge  If I consider now the one-point compactification $\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$ and the set of probability measures on it. Do we still have the same equivalence?

Comment: @IosifPinelis If I consider now the one-point compactification $\mathbb R\cup \{\infty\}$ and the set of probability measures on it. Do we still have the same equivalence?

Comment: How are you defining the cumulative distribution function for a measure on $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$?  What for instance is the cdf of a point mass at infinity?

Comment: @NateEldredge For this case, we define $F_{\mu}(x):=\int_{(-\infty, x]}\mu(dz)$ for all $x\in\overline{\mathbb R}$. By definition one has $F_{\mu}(\infty):=\int_{(-\infty, \infty]}\mu(dz)=1$, while one may have the discontinuity at $\infty$, i.e. $F_{\mu}(\infty)>\lim_{x\to\infty}F_{\mu}(x)$.

Comment: After your edit of the original condition 3 (by adding the condition $\mu_n((-\infty,\infty))\to\mu((-\infty,\infty))$), there is no need for compactification. If you remove the compactification part, then I think I can write a proof of the equivalence of the original three conditions. BTW, different conditions should be denoted differently -- right now, you have two different sets of conditions 1, 2, 3.